# Is there a way to access a structs fields as an array?

Tags: java, arrays, struct, rust

I'm new to rust and am trying to figure out if this is possible.

So sometimes it's cleaner for functions/methods to access data as an array, and sometimes it's cleaner to access data by name

in rust I can define something like this:

```
struct Vector3D{
    x : f64,
    y : f64,
    z : f64,
    coordinates : [f64;3]
}
```

But there needs to only be a single place where each value is stored.

In Java what I'm asking for is (I believe) not possible and the solution I use is this:

```
public class Vector3D {
    public static class Vec3D {
        public static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 3;
        public static final int X = 0;
        public static final int Y = 1;
        public static final int Z = 2;
    }
    private double[] coords;

    public double x(){
        return coords[Vec3D.X];
    }
}
```

which is a bit kludgy, but allows me to access the values of the fixed size arrays by name.

Is there a better way to do something like this in Rust?

Comment: You could implement [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) for your `Vector3D`

Comment: Do you know if accessing struct elements via the Index trait is O(1) or O(n) in the number of members in the struct? In that reference it looks like O(n) due to the match

Comment: @BenBooth Arrays are contiguous, so usual indexing is O(1). But you could implement `Index` for a very complicated type of your own and this implementation would have a higher complexity (search through an internal linked list for example...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version using Index & IndexMut but without any match statements & with the raw data stored as an array

```
use core::ops::Index;
use core::ops::IndexMut;
fn main() {
    
    let mut v = Vector3D {
        coordinates: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    };
    
    println!("v={:?}", v);
    
    // can read/write by name
    v[Vec3D::X] = v[Vec3D::Y] + 2.0;
    
    println!("v={:?}", v);
    
    // can read/write by directly indexing
    v[2] = v[Vec3D::X] - v[1];
    
    println!("v={:?}", v);
}

enum Vec3D{
    X = 0,
    Y,
    Z,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector3D {
    coordinates: [f64;3],
}

impl Index<Vec3D> for Vector3D {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, coordinate: Vec3D) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.coordinates[coordinate as usize]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<Vec3D> for Vector3D {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, coordinate: Vec3D) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.coordinates[coordinate as usize]
    }
}

impl Index<usize> for Vector3D {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, coordinate: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.coordinates[coordinate]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<usize> for Vector3D {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, coordinate: usize) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.coordinates[coordinate]
    }
}
```

Or alternatively the Vector3D struct could be removed entirely

```
use core::ops::Index;
use core::ops::IndexMut;

// this allows us to use Vector3D in place of [f64;3]
type Vector3D = [f64;3];

fn main() {
    
    // without this v[X] would be v[Vec3D::X] etc
    use crate::Vec3D::*;
    
    let mut v : Vector3D = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];

    println!("v={:?}", v);
    
    // can read/write by name
    v[X] = v[Y] + 2.0;
    
    println!("v={:?}", v);
    
    // can read/write by directly indexing
    v[2] = v[X] - v[1];
    
    println!("v={:?}", v);
    
}

enum Vec3D{
    X = 0,
    Y,
    Z,
}

impl Index<Vec3D> for Vector3D {
    type Output = f64;

    fn index(&self, coordinate: Vec3D) -> &Self::Output {
        &self[coordinate as usize]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<Vec3D> for Vector3D {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, coordinate: Vec3D) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self[coordinate as usize]
    }
}
```

which has the advantage of brevity and compile-time index-out-of-bounds checks
but does (for better or worse) implement the name based indexing for all arrays of type [f64;3]

Answer (score 3):

You can keep `coordinates` as main storage and provide methods to access each of them by their names.
Moreover, implementing `Index`/`IndexMut` traits gives some comfort.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector3D {
    coordinates: [f64; 3],
}

impl Vector3D {
    fn x(&self) -> f64 {
        self.coordinates[0]
    }
    fn y(&self) -> f64 {
        self.coordinates[1]
    }
    fn z(&self) -> f64 {
        self.coordinates[2]
    }
    fn x_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.coordinates[0]
    }
    fn y_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.coordinates[1]
    }
    fn z_mut(&mut self) -> &mut f64 {
        &mut self.coordinates[2]
    }
}

impl std::ops::Index<usize> for Vector3D {
    type Output = f64;
    fn index(
        &self,
        idx: usize,
    ) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.coordinates[idx]
    }
}

impl std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for Vector3D {
    fn index_mut(
        &mut self,
        idx: usize,
    ) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.coordinates[idx]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vector3D {
        coordinates: [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
    };
    println!("x={}, y={}, z={}", v.x(), v.y(), v.z());
    *v.x_mut() += 10.01;
    *v.y_mut() += 20.02;
    *v.z_mut() += 30.03;
    for idx in 0..3 {
        println!("v[{}]={}", idx, v[idx]);
        v[idx] *= -1.0;
    }
    println!("v={:?}", v);
}
/*
x=1.1, y=2.2, z=3.3
v[0]=11.11
v[1]=22.22
v[2]=33.33
v=Vector3D { coordinates: [-11.11, -22.22, -33.33] }
*/
```

Comment: That's cool! I didn't realize how the mutable borrows would allow use of += syntax.
So If I understand correctly, the Vector3D struct is and remains the owner of the array (and it's values) but they are borrowed by others so they can be accessed or changed

Comment: @BenBooth yes, exactly, the main data (`coordinates`) are stored and owned in one place, but we provide accessors in order to read/write them.

Answer (score 2):

based on @vallentin's comment I put together this code which I feel directly answers the question:

```
 use core::ops::Index;
    use core::ops::IndexMut;
    fn main() {
        
        let mut v = Vector3D{x:1.0,y:2.0,z:3.0};
        
        println!("v={:?}", v);
        
        // can read/write by name
        v.x = v.y + 2.0;
        
        println!("v={:?}", v);
        
        // can read/write by directly indexing
        v[2] = v.x - v[1];
        
        println!("v={:?}", v);
    }
    
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Vector3D {
        x: f64,
        y: f64,
        z: f64,
    }
    
    impl Index<usize> for Vector3D {
        type Output = f64;
    
        fn index(&self, coordinate: usize) -> &Self::Output {
            
            match coordinate {
                0 => &self.x,
                1 => &self.y,
                2 => &self.z,
                _ => panic!("Invalid Vector3D index: {}", coordinate),
            }
        }
    }
    
    impl IndexMut<usize> for Vector3D {
        fn index_mut(&mut self, coordinate: usize) -> &mut f64 {
            
            match coordinate {
                0 => &mut self.x,
                1 => &mut self.y,
                2 => &mut self.z,
                _ => panic!("Invalid Vector3D index: {}", coordinate),
            }
        }
    }

Output:
v=Vector3D { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0 }
v=Vector3D { x: 4.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0 }
v=Vector3D { x: 4.0, y: 2.0, z: 2.0 }
```

basically using the Index & IndexMut traits allows the struct to be directly index for read-only or read-write access

Comment: I understood your question in the opposite direction, sorry about that. However, I find much more natural accessing individual elements of an array than considering as an array something which is absolutely not one (whatever the programming language).

Comment: In case you are interested in code efficiency, I compared the optimized code of this match-based solution with the one of an array index. This match-based solution implies three comparisons + jumps; the array-based just implies a bound-check before the actual memory access.

Comment: I don't have a strong preference between whether the data is internally stored as an array or as fields in a struct. I would like clean readable data access via either indexing or by name and I need memory efficiency (shouldn't take up much more memory than the raw data) and I need O(1) access time in the number of elements (which this apparently doesn't have)